# How to make Entity Framework Code First use the SQL Azure DB?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, ef-code-first, azure-sql-database

I'm start to learn EF now. What I want to do is use EF code first create new tables in SQL Azure.

Here is my code:

```
namespace WebApplication2
{
   public class Blog
   {
       public int UserName { get; set; }
       public int ID { get; set; }
   }

   public class BlogContext : DbContext
   {
       public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

       public BlogContext() : base("MYEF")
       {
       }
   }
}
```

Code behind:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        using (var db = new BlogContext())
        {
            var blog = new Blog { UserName = 456 };
            db.Blogs.Add(blog);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

`Web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestDBContext" 
         connectionString="Server=tcp:mydb.database.windows.net,1433;Database=MYEF;User ID=[Username];Password=[MyPassword];Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;PersistSecurityInfo=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When I check my SQL Azure DB, no table has been created, EF still create the table `MYEF` in the default SQL Server Express database.

Has anyone done this successfully?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should pass the connection string name to the base constructor of your `BlogContext` like this

```
public BlogContext()
    : base("TestDBContext")
{
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: Thanksssssss very much~~ You save my life!

Answer (score 0):

EntityFramework tries to infer the name of the ConnectionString in the web/app.config file from the name of the class which inherits DbContext. In your case, this is BlogContext.

If you simply changed

```
<connectionStrings><add name="TestDBContext"
```

to

```
<connectionStrings><add name="BlogContext"
```

then you  could do `public BlogContext()` without passing a hard string to the base class.